# How to integrate vert.x and JOOQ (with Autogenerated DAO and POJO and Connection Pooling)

Tags: jooq, vert.x

As I know vert.x is event Based. so I am going to use JOOQ autogenerated DAO from worker verticle.

Comment: OK. Go for it :) Now, what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog post](http://qrman.github.io/posts/2015/10/05/vertx-guice-jooq-ultm/) about Vert.x and jOOQ integration. You may find it useful.